# removeSpriteFramesFromFile doesn't seem to work

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using CCScrollLayer. and I'm trying to prepare a level's texture at the stage select screen before level is started. 
 So, I made this screen as when I change level, then before level's textured that was prepared is supposed to be removed. But I don't think "removeSpriteFramesFromFile" method work well. because when I scroll the several layer, It suddenly call "Memory warning" and remove that textures at that late time then I expected.

```
-(void) prepareTexture:(NSNumber*)number
{
    int _page = [number intValue];

    if(loadingTexNum != 0 && (_page + 1) != loadingTexNum)
    {
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFramesFromFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"L%d.plist", loadingTexNum]];
        loadingTexNum = _page + 1;
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"L%d.plist", loadingTexNum]];
    }

    if(loadingTexNum == 0 && (_page + 1) != loadingTexNum)
    {
        loadingTexNum = _page + 1;
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"L%d.plist", loadingTexNum]];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that first `if` definitely called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you misunderstood what that method does:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFramesFromFile:@"file.plist"];
```

It loads the sprite frames in the plist, then removes the CCSpriteFrame objects in that plist from the cache - if they are cached. It does NOT remove the texture, only the CCSpriteFrame objects!

To remove a texture from the cache you need to call:

```
 [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture:tex];
```

You should know that a CCSpriteFrame object is a relatively light-weight object that consumes at most 64 Bytes of memory. That is nothing compared to even a very small 32x32 texture with 16-bit color depth which uses 2048 Bytes of memory.

Comment: Thanks your help. Ok I looked cocos2d's code. You are right. "CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:texturePath];" is called in addSpriteFramesWithFile method. then I should figure out how to remove specific texture that I want to remove. Thanks